# Error php and mymql

Tags: php, mysql

First time programming a simple database. 
But I cant figure out how to solve this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   W:...\index.php on line 39

This is my script..

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM studenten");

echo "<table border='1'>

<tr>
<th>first name</th>
<th>last name</th>
<th>studentnummer</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  id = $row[id]; //this is line 39
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['voornaam'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['studentnummer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <a href ='edit.php?id_student=$id'>Edit</a>";
  echo "<td> <a href ='delete.php?id_student=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";
  echo "</tr>";
}                     

echo "</table>";
```

can someone help me?

Comment: forget $ and quotes `$id = $row['id'];` //this is line 39

Comment: change `id = $row[id];`     to      $id = $row['id'];

Comment: yeah, `id` is being treated as a constant. (for one thing).

Comment: Not enough coffee yet. Change that row to be `$id = $row['id'];` Note the `$` for the variable and the quotes around the array key identifier.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard  how to store value in variable inside the loop it returns in array format

Comment: What do you mean @KarthikKeyan

Comment: Not possible to store the variable inside the loop i this it stored in array format like $id[] = $row['id'];

Comment: Guys, You we are all putting minus to question , It just a question

Answer (score 1):

```
id = $row[id]; //this is line 39
```

Shouldn't that be

```
$id = $row['id']; //this is line 39
```

You're missing the `$` from your `id` variable and quotes for your array key.

Answer (score 1):

use

`mysqli_fetch_assoc`

because

```
mysqli_fetch_array
```

returns a indexed array

and on line 39

```
$id = $row['id'];
```